# Play asset pipeline is not generating the minified version of the js files in production?

Tags: javascript, playframework, sbt, minify, uglifyjs

Having a Play 2.4 web application, I'm trying to use [sbt-uglify](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-uglify) to create `.min.js` from my `.js` files.

**Route declaration**:

```
GET  /assets/*file  controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

**Pipeline stages**:

```
pipelineStages := Seq(uglify)
```

**Overriden `Assets.at`**:

```
override def at(path: String, fileName: String, cacheAggressively: Boolean): Action[AnyContent] = {
    super.at(path, redirectToMin(path, fileName), cacheAggressively)
}

private def redirectToMin(path: String, fileName: String): String = {
    val resourceName = some logic to crated the minfile...
    Play.maybeApplication.flatMap(_.resource(resourceName).map(_ => minFile)).getOrElse(fileName)
}
```

To test everything works in dev mode, as suggested in this [post](https://www.mschweighauser.com/playframework-asset-pipeline/), I use `pipelineStages in Assets := Seq(uglify)`, and the minified javascript files are generated. However, when I start the application with `start` to indicate we are in production, the minified versions are not generated. Any thoughts on where I look next would be really appreciated.

**PS1**: I'm using sbt-uglify-1.0.3, if it makes any difference.

**PS2**: I'm using [sbt-less](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-less) for the stylesheets, and those are minified correctly.

Comment: Why did you need your own Assets controller? The out-of-the-box Assets controller has all the logic necessary to access the minified files. Also, are you sure the files were not created? `.min.js` files are created at `target/web/rjs` and later packaged as a webjar.

Comment: Thanks for editing the post btw.

Yeah I have to revisit my controller, it's a legacy one before Play2.3..

I'm not using rjs, just uglify. When I run it in development mode with `pipelineStages in Assets := Seq(uglify)` the .min.js are created at "target\web\public\main\javascripts".
So When I run my server using "start", I was thinking it should generate the .min.js in the same place. That's not the case?